# Ping 8.8.8.8 returned "Reply from [IP of modem]: destination net unreachable"

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, ping

I am using Windows 10 and having issues with my Wi-Fi dropping out sporadically, sometimes up to 10 times during an hour. I have performed a ping test while being directly connected to the modem through ethernet. After pinging for 3 hours, I was able to log zero packet loss and very low latency.

After scrolling through the log I found 3 cases of the message "Reply from [IP of modem]: destination net unreachable". The three cases did not happen consecutively.

What can I assume from this information?

Ping results through the wired connection are:

```
Ping statistics for 8.8.8.8: 
Packets: Sent = 10674, Received = 10674, Lost = 0 (0% loss), Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds: Minimum = 9ms, Maximum = 15ms, Average = 9ms
```

Some lines from the test:

```
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=57
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=57
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=57
Reply from 192.168.1.1: Destination net unreachable.
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=57
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=57
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=57
```

Link to a [PasteBin containing the log](https://pastebin.com/N6AeFfMJ) when connected to modem with wire.

Link to a [PasteBin of the log](https://pastebin.com/i9UrXjuY) when connected to router with wire, which again is connected to the modem with wire.

Link to a [PasteBin of the log](https://pastebin.com/tTGbDjVh) when connected to Wi-Fi.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144716/discussion-on-question-by-lookupdown-ping-8-8-8-8-returned-reply-from-ip-of-mo); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score -4):

The interesting message in your first log is :

> Reply from 192.168.1.1: Destination net unreachable.

The IP address `192.168.1.1` surely relates to your router that is the
gateway for your local network. The router then drops out from time to time for a short instant.

My understanding is that if the router became unavailable, no pings
were sent, which explains why these errors did not cause any lost
messages.

I suggest to :

- Reboot the router/modem
- If the problem persists, check if you can find a firmware update
  for the router
- For good measure, check if a newer driver exists for your network adapter.

---

Apart from the first and somewhat puzzling log, your new logs
show more usual statistics.
In these logs you have packet loss, so it's a quite ordinary
occurrence where the problem is clearly the ISP timing out on
requests. In these cases we can see that the lost packets
crossed over to the router and died there, coming back with
a clear error code.

There is very little chance that the problem was with the
Google DNS site itself, so it's clearly with the ISP and
its service to your place.

In one such case ping had 4 consequent such errors, which
means that the interruption in service lasted about 4 seconds.

You should contact and complain to your ISP Support.
Doing the above maintenance acts to your router should be done
first, in case Support will ask about them.

Comment: I don't understand how a router producing a response (rather than the intended host) leads you to the conclusion that the router was down. It's a proof that it was available.

Comment: @gronostaj: `192.168.1.x` became unreachable, and this is the router. I don't think that this error was returned by the router, rather that it was produced in the local computer. Otherwise it would mean that the ISP had become very briefly unreachable, I can only think because of an elapsed DHCP lease (DHCP renewal every hour is too far-fetched).

Comment: Where does it say that 192.168.1.x became unreachable?

Comment: @gronostaj: In the text added by the poster to his post. I quoted the line above.

Comment: @harrymc - no, 192.168.1.1 (most likely the main router) momentarily did not know how to reach the destination (8.8.8.8) - that's not the router being unavailable (it's responded for a start, so it's available) that's the route (to 8.8.8.8) being unavailable for any number of reasons that have may or may not have anything to do with the router

Comment: @JaromandaX: This statement should be backed by an explanation for: (1) What could cause a router to lose network for a fraction of a second, (2) Why would an ICMP package that crossed over to the router and came back with an error code not be counted as lost. In any case, the measures I've recommended are basically all that the poster can reasonably do, so why downvote an answer that can only help, even if you don't agree with the theory behind it.

Comment: 1) many reasons, 2) no idea

Comment: @JaromandaX: My theory that no message was lost because no message was sent may be wrong, but for the moment is the only theory. My answer was downvoted twice because of claims that the error happened on the router, but so far nobody was able to offer an alternative explanation. Unexplained downvotes are problematic. You're not responsible for the other downvote, so excuse me for only addressing you.

Comment: @harrymc I have added a ping log from connection through wifi as well. For me it seems that the router (modem) was not able to find google and therefore no package was sent. Could this be a fault in the signal coming from outside the building, or is it more likely in the modem itself?

Comment: In the additional logs you have packet loss, so it's a quite ordinary occurrence, unlike the first one you published. The problem in them is clearly the ISP timing out on requests. In these cases the lost packets crossed over to the router and died there, coming back with a clear error code. There is no chance that the problem was with the Google DNS site itself, the problem is clearly with the ISP and its service to your place.

Comment: In one such case ping had 4 consequent such errors, which means that the interruption in service lasted about 4 seconds.

Comment: I had added this information to my answer.

Comment: _"so far nobody was able to offer an alternative explanation"_ - true, but that doesn't make your answer any better. _"Unexplained downvotes are problematic"_ - also true, but this is not the case here. I have given my explanation in the very first comment: your conclusions contradict the message that you drew them from and you have provided no convincing explanation why it should be read backwards. User Jaromanda X also explained this in their words. You may not like these explanations, but that hardly makes the downvotes unexplained.

Comment: @gronostaj: You say that this error comes from the router. An explanation why a supposedly dropped message is not counted would help. My answer may be wrong, as it's based on the pure logic that not counted means not existing.